# xpath query for Linkedin profile

Tags: xml, xpath, google-sheets

I been trying to extract urls of search results from linkedin search using xpath code.
Here is the sample link which I want to extract search results urls using xpath in google spreadsheet

https://www.linkedin.com/vsearch/p?openAdvancedForm=true&locationType=Y&f_G=us%3A100,us%3A344,us%3A516,us%3A524,us%3A860,us%3A265,us%3A218,us%3A58,us%3A203,us%3A288&f_CC=2152&rsid=2713073761454724726897&orig=ADVS

Here is another one which I want to extract public url from linkedin profile after login.
Here is an example profile url which I want to extract public url using xpath in google spreadsheet

https://www.linkedin.com/in/benjaminbeutel?authType=OUT_OF_NETWORK&authToken=p-fm&locale=en_US&srchid=2713073761454724761909&srchindex=1&srchtotal=123&trk=vsrp_people_res_name&trkInfo=VSRPsearchId%3A2713073761454724761909%2CVSRPtargetId%3A169874133%2CVSRPcmpt%3Aprimary%2CVSRPnm%3Afalse%2CauthType%3AOUT_OF_NETWORK

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues with what your trying to do - certain pages on linkedin can easily be pulled in via xpath - but that only applies to fully public facing profiles, such as company profiles -

you cannot perform the linked in people search that way, with the exception of using Blockspring (blockspring.com) - a chrome extension - uses their people search api and conveniently injects it into your spreadsheet for you - they actually have a ton of really useful connectors,